# .NET Core Options pattern config registration using assembly scanning

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am working on a .NET Core web application with several configuration instances registered to the `IServiceCollection`, meaning the startup code contains many lines of the following form:

`builder.Services.Configure<T>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("KeyFromAppSettingsFile");`

where T is the model the config will bind to and builder is the `WebApplicationBuilder`. In the interest of keeping the startup code more concise/readable, I am trying to move these registrations to an extension method in another file that scans the assembly for classes with a specific attribute.

Thus far I have been able to create the attribute (constructor accepts the key that was previously passed to `builder.Configuration.GetSection()`), apply it to the config classes, and scan the assembly to get a collection of `Type` where the attribute is defined. The issue is that it does not appear possible to do a similar config registration to what I showed above using an instance of a `Type`. Here is what I have currently:

Attribute class:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class TestAttribute: Attribute
{
    public string Key { get; private set; }

    public TestAttribute(string configKey)
    {
        Key = configKey;
    }
}
```

Extension method:

```
public static void RegisterConfig(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                                    .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes())
                                    .Where(type => type != null && type.IsDefined(TestAttribute, false));
    foreach (var type in types)
    {
        var attrData = type?.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestAttribute), false).First() as TestAttribute;
        
        builder.Configuration.GetSection(attrData?.Key).Bind(type); //runtime exception since type is not generic
    }
}
```

Seeing as I am relatively new to .NET and OOP I also tried
`builder.Services.Configure<config>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(attr.Key));`
but config is a variable not a type and cannot be used as a generic type argument.

In summary, the desired behavior is to bind appsettings.json configuration to basic models using a list of Types fetched from an assembly scan. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the generic method Configure<T>, as you have in your original code.

The Configure method is an extension method declared in Microsoft.Extensions.Dependency Injection:

```
namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Extension methods for adding configuration related options services to the DI container.
    /// </summary>
    public static class OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Registers a configuration instance which TOptions will bind against.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TOptions">The type of options being configured.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="services">The <see cref="IServiceCollection"/> to add the services to.</param>
        /// <param name="config">The configuration being bound.</param>
        /// <returns>The <see cref="IServiceCollection"/> so that additional calls can be chained.</returns>
        [RequiresDynamicCode(OptionsBuilderConfigurationExtensions.RequiresDynamicCodeMessage)]
        [RequiresUnreferencedCode(OptionsBuilderConfigurationExtensions.TrimmingRequiredUnreferencedCodeMessage)]
        public static IServiceCollection Configure<[DynamicallyAccessedMembers(DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.All)] TOptions>(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config) where TOptions : class
            => services.Configure<TOptions>(Options.Options.DefaultName, config);
```

You'll need to call this method using reflection:

```
public static void RegisterConfig(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                        .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes())
                        .Where(type => type != null && type.IsDefined(typeof(TestAttribute), false));

    foreach (var type in types)
    {
        var attrData = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestAttribute), false).First() as TestAttribute;
        var configureMethod = typeof(OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions)
            .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
            .First(m => m.Name == "Configure" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
            .MakeGenericMethod(type);

        configureMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { builder.Services, builder.Configuration.GetSection(attrData.Key) });
    }
}
```